# Unexpected token in JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

Quiero leer la información JSON recibida de una petición AJAX.

Código .js

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "includes/modelos/modelo-contacto.php", true);

xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        console.log($respuesta);  
    }
}
xhr.send(datos);
```

Código PHP

```
    $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'correcto',
        'datos' => array(
            'nombre' => $nombre,
            'empresa' => $empresa,
            'telefono' => $telefono,
            'id_insertado' => $statement->insert_id,
        )
    );
   echo json_encode ($respuesta);
```

Estoy haciendo un curso y el código es el mismo que utiliza el profesor. 
He probado a crear yo la variable $respuesta con el código JSON tal cual para después hacer un echo de la variable sin el encode y también he probado a devolver solamente "respuesta" => "correcto" (por si fuera que estoy construyendo mal el JSON) y aún así me sigue dando el mismo error.

También he leído que es un problema que suele dar XAMPP pero he subido los archivos a un hosting de estos gratuitos y sigue dando el mismo fallo.

A ver si a alguien le ha pasado.

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Podrías probar a hacer un console.log(xhr.responseText) antes de parsearlo, para ver que te está llegando.

Comment: `console.log($respuesta);` en el código Javascript declaraste respuesta y en el console.log colocaste `$respuesta`; colocaste de mas el simbolo de $

Comment: Iñigo Irigoyen! gracias a eso lo he solucionado, daba un fallo el documento php porque no estaba definida una variable anterior y por eso luego al devolver el json no lo podía parsear. 
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:
Opcion1:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xhr.open("POST", "includes/modelos/modelo-contacto.php", true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        console.log(respuesta);  
    }
```

**Opcion 2:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';

xhr.open("POST", "includes/modelos/modelo-contacto.php", true);

xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

        console.log(respuesta);  
    }
```

Opcion 3 actual:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Y en el php tienes una coma de mas:

```
$respuesta = array( 'respuesta' => 'correcto', 'datos' => array( 'nombre' => $nombre, 'empresa' => $empresa, 'telefono' => $telefono, 'id_insertado' => $statement->insert_id ) ); echo json_encode ($respuesta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nada, lo he modificado con las dos opciones y sigue dándome el mismo error:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");

xhr.open("POST", "includes/modelos/modelo-contacto.php", true);

xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(respuesta);
    }
```

Y el PHP también lo he corregido aunque eso había sido un fallo al copiarlo aquí:

```
    $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'correcto',
        'datos' => array(
            'nombre' => $nombre,
            'empresa' => $empresa,
            'telefono' => $telefono,
            'id_insertado' => $statement->insert_id
        )
    );
```

Después probaré con fetch pero no entiendo el fallo con AJAX.

Muchas gracias igualmente!!

Comment: Santiago Muchas gracias por el comentario de XAMPP, cambie por MAMP y me funcionó perfecto